# why do I have extra output '@{..}' in my powershell script?

Tags: powershell

When I run the following script it returns: `@{Name=<Usersname>} not found`

```
Foreach ($object in Get-childitem "\\HomeDriveServer\home$\" | select Name)
{
$userAccount = get-aduser -Filter {SamAccountName -like "*$object*"}
if($userAccount -eq $null)
    {
write-host "$object not found"
    }
else
    {
write-host "$object found"
    }
}
```

`Get-childitem "\\HomeDriveServer\home$\" | select Name` returns the list of folder names fine without the `@{Name=`XXX`}`

why is the `@{Name=`XXX`}` appearing, and how can I get rid of it?

Thanks

Comment: That's how hash tables are displayed.

Comment: Use `Select -expand Name` in Your first line. You're comparing an Object with a name property to `SamAccountName`, not the name value(a string) like you should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is not exactly what you get. Your query returns a collection. 
You should try :

```
Foreach ($object in Get-childitem "\\HomeDriveServer\home$\" | select -ExpandProperty Name)
{
$userAccount = get-aduser -Filter {SamAccountName -like "*$object*"}
if($userAccount -eq $null)
    {
write-host "$object not found"
    }
else
    {
write-host "$object found"
    }
}
```